# Resize JTable fontSize with the increase or decrease in JTable row height

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to resize the font size with the change in the row height of a `JTable`. The row height of the table is configurable in the `application.properties` file, so every time application starts it gets the configured row height and render the table.

**Now** row height is getting changed with the provided settings in the `application.properties` file But...

**Problem Is :** the font size of each cell aren't getting updated if row height changes and only the row height gets bigger if I increase the setting in the properties file.

I'm trying to implement this change in table's constructor so that new instance gets instantiated by the provided configurations.

```
public class CustomTable extends JTable 
{
    . . . 
    . . .


    public CustomTable(String name, User user, boolean isOffice) {
        this(name, user != null && user.isPermissed("ALLOW_GRID_RESIZE", "Terminal"), isOffice);
        this.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        this.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        if(!isOffice)
        {
            // This change is getting rendered
            this.setRowHeight(ApplicationSettings.getTableRowHeight());

            // For some reason these changes aren't getting rendere
            Font font = this.getFont();
            font = font.deriveFont(((float) (font.getSize2D() * (1 + ApplicationSettings.getTableRowHeight()/100))));
            this.setFont(font);         
        }
    }
    . . .
    . . .
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *"`public class CustomTable extends JTable`"* I have yet to see a case where it makes sense to extend a table. Why is it being done here?

Comment: Well It provides customisation and to maintain the consistency according to the need. And for the same reasons being used here as well.

Comment: Is the problem your custom table? We don't have access to your code or your  configuration file. So first get it working with JDK classes and hardcoded data.  So create a simple example (see first comment) that simply contains a Jframe with a standard JTable. You can hardcode the row height and font size. Next step is to create a combox with a list a setting and see if you can change it dynamically. Finally once you get this working you can try the code with your configuration file.

Comment: Also, don't try to set the font size in that complicated statement. First create a variable that does the size calculation. Then use that variable in the deriveFont() method. That way you can debug your code and display the value to make sure it is a reasonable size.

Comment: The fact that the RowHeight is getting changed with the change in application.properties shows that my configuration are being picked from the properties file. 2nd You might have noticed that I'm using the same getTableRowHeight() value as a factor to increase the font size. Am I missing something while setting `this.setFont(font)` ??